# Binding tinyMCE with knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, tinymce-4

Try to use tinyMCE custom binding using.
My Model C#:

```
    public sealed class CabinetShapeEditModel
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

In view:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var jso = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(jso);
</script>
```

My HTML:

```
<div style="min-height: 250px; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 5px;">
          <textarea data-bind="wysiwyg: Description, wysiwygConfig: {selector:selector, menubar:false, statusbar : false, height: 210, toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | link unlink | image | media | charmap| code | table | ltr rtl | emoticons | forecolor backcolor | fullscreen | preview', plugins: 'hr,link,image,charmap,preview,code,fullscreen,insertdatetime,media,table,directionality,emoticons,textcolor'  }"></textarea>
</div><script type="text/javascript">
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);</script>
```

JavaScript: https://github.com/michaelpapworth/tinymce-knockout-binding

But always recives Error:
Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "wysiwyg: function (){return Description }"
Message: Object [object Object] has no method 'tinymce'

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The error `Message: Object [object Object] has no method 'tinymce'` would suggest that you haven't included the `jquery.tinymce.min.js` plugin.  I have since updated the [docs](https://github.com/michaelpapworth/tinymce-knockout-binding/blob/master/README.md) to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

Try

1. including the [debug version of the wysiwyg binding](https://github.com/michaelpapworth/tinymce-knockout-binding/blob/master/wysiwyg.debug.js) instead of the compressed one, if you haven't already
2. in your developer tools (Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug), go to the Scripts panel and set a breakpoint on line 57

   ```
   $(element).text(value).tinymce(defaults);
   ```

Now reload the page. This should trigger the debugger before the error occurs.

`$(element)` should be your textarea, `value` should be your `Description`. While the dev tools have stopped on the breakpoint, open the Console, run these steps manually and see if anything returns something unexpected:

```
$(element)
$(element).text(value)
$(element).text(value).tinymce(defaults)
```